# Serving webpack built assets from a subdirectory

Tags: build, webpack

In all the examples I've seen, the entrypoint html file (e.g. index.html) lives alongside all the built assets emitted by webpack.

```
build/
  index.html
  bundle.js
  1.bundle.js
  2.bundle.js
  etc
```

I'd like to have my entrypoint html separate from the built assets:

```
index.html
build/
  bundle.js
  1.bundle.js
  2.bundle.js
  etc
```

Is this possible with webpack?

Comment: I should add that my app uses CSS with external images and fonts. When I load the bundles from an html file in the parent directory, those asset paths break.

Answer (score 14):

Aha, figured it out. In the webpack.config, you have to set `output.publicPath`. That path is used to prefix all relative URLs in CSS.

In my case, I used:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve('./build'),
    publicPath: './build/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath

Comment: Are you using HTMLWebpackPlugin to generate the index.html file as well? By default wouldn't the html file be output in the same directory?